# Здравствуйте. Проблема со slick слайдером

Tags: slider, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]При первом запуске страницы не отображаются картинки в slider-top. Но если я перезагружу страницу, то всё будет отображаться корректно. Или же (самое странное), если я через консоль добавлю/отниму пиксель к ширине картинки, то она тоже появится...
После очистки кеша снова пропадает изображение

[image: Код js]

[image: Собственно первый запуск страницы на сервере.]

Comment: Покажите весь свой код и рабочий слайдер после этого вам помогут.

Comment: Добавил фото самого кода.

Comment: Попробуйте не в document.ready инициировать слайдер, а в window.load